# Turning off all sibling tooltips when a new one is clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm building a site using Bootstrap 2.3.2 (because it's a Joomla site which doesn't support version 3 yet), and I'm using the Tooltips widget to describe the various features of a product. So I have a bunch of dots superimposed on the product image, and when the user clicks/taps on a dot, a tooltip appears above it to describe that feature. (Because this needs to work on mobile, and there is no hover state on mobile, the trigger needs to be set to click instead of hover. My next question would be how can you change the trigger type based on browser width.) Currently, the only way to get the tooltip to disappear is to click/tap on it again. How can I set it so all the sibling tooltips turn off whenever a new one is turned on?

Here's the basic code I've got now:

```
$('.dot').tooltip({
    trigger: "click"
});
```

I've tried hiding all tooltips before displaying the new one, but something's wrong with my syntax because it doesn't work:

```
$('.dot').click(function() {
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
    $(this).tooltip({
        trigger: "click"
    });
});
```

I figure there's probably some easy way to target the .dot's siblings and chain a hide command to the existing tooltip function, but I'm not Javascript savvy enough to figure it out. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$('.dot')` instead of `$(this)` to hide all the tooltip:

```
$('.dot').click(function() {
    $('.dot').tooltip('hide');
    $(this).tooltip({
        trigger: "click"
    });
});
```